# C++, innerclasses and why you can only create members as pointers to them

Tags: c++, inner-classes

Why is it that you can only create a pionter to an inner class as a member of the enclosing class.
How is it aranged in memory and why does it prevent this, ex:

```
class temp  
{  
    public:

    class inner
    {
    public:
        inner(int a = 0) : memberInt(a) {}
        const int memberInt;
    };

    temp(int i = 0) : member(i)  
    {  
    }  
    inner *i; // this works  
    inner i; // this doesn't  
    int member;  
};
```

Thanks in advance :-).

Comment: Your premise that `inner i;` is invalid is incorrect.  Both `inner* i;` and `inner i;` are valid declarations of member variables in `temp`.  What compiler rejects `inner i;`?  [On an unrelated note, it's probably better to refer to this as a _nested class_ in C++, to avoid confusion with _inner classes_ in Java, which are quite different.]

Comment: I'm sure that this is perfectly legal, having used it many times. The only reason I can see why it would not be legal is if you declared the members before the inner class -- you could still make a pointer work with a forward declaration.

Comment: The only "illegal" thing I see here is the fact that he has two identifiers called "i" within the temp class.

Comment: I didn't have both written at the same time, it couldnt' have been a name clash

Comment: Then either (a) the code you have posted is different from the code with which you had this problem (very likely) or (b) you have found a compiler bug (highly unlikely).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code actually compiles fine for me in g++, assuming I rename the second one (inner i) to inner i2.

This is the exact code I compiled in g++:

```
class temp  
{  
    public:

    class inner
    {
    public:
        inner(int a = 0) : memberInt(a) {}
        const int memberInt;
    };

    temp(int i = 0) : member(i)  
    {  
    }  

    inner *i;
    inner i2;
    int member;  
}; 


int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have it workings as u have it, but one thing that was a little different in my source was I had passed arguments to the constructor of the i2 object, and this does give me error, and idea why? thank you :-)

Comment: sry dumb question, I'm supposed to pass those in the constructor of temp X-(

Comment: @rubixibuc: Can you post the exact code that was giving you an error?

Comment: I'm just getting back into c++, since about 10 years have past.

Comment: @Mike, I was doing something like inner i(4); but my lack of experience thus far had me mistaken that is not proper. :-)

Comment: @rubixibuc: No problem. If you've found the issue, then good job.